# Is it possible to set notepad++ as a query editor in db2

Tags: db2, sql-pl

I have just installed db2 on windows 8.1 and I want to run some queries. Ideally it would be easier using an editor like notepad++ to edit the queries before running them on the db2 command line as opposed to using the db2 command line. How do I set it up?

I tried this link and it did not work for me.
https://www.databasejournal.com/features/db2/article.php/10896_3316861_3/DB2-Command-Line-Processor-Tips-and-Tricks.htm

Comment: The method works fine for me on Windoze7 and with Db2 v11.1 and my text-editor on Windoze is gvim.   Improve the clarity of your question, or describe more clearly exactly what did not work. If you want to work with TEXT files to contain your SQL queries and Db2 commands, you can use db2cmd.exe , or cygwin.  If you want to combine SQL queries and result sets in one replayable consider using Jupyter notebooks. If you want a GUI consider that combines SQL-editing and result-set grids consider tools like IBM-Data-Studio or DB-Visualizer or any of many freely available GUIs that work with Db2.

Comment: I would like to edit errors in queries on notepad++ after running them. Running EDIT EDITOR notepad++ gives me and error message db21036e

Comment: The feature is intended to work from the interactive CLP , after you correctly set the relevant variables (or Db2 registry variable). The editor should either be on the PATH or relevant variable fully qualified. The method is not intended for shell use, it will only operate inside CLP interactive mode.

Comment: I decided to use DB-Visualizer. It connected. Thank you for the suggestion.